# Why does this function not work within the eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, addeventlistener

I am just starting with JavaScript and for my first project I am trying to display a working calculator using JS, HTML and CSS. I am just one step away from it finally handling easy operations but for some reason my "solver"-function does not work when hitting the Enter-button.

I already tried out all the functions in a "test.js" console.logging the results and everything worked perfectly. But for some reason it won't work when combining it with the eventListener and trying to display it within the textfield. I also tried simpler functions and displaying only variables in the textfield which works. It is just the solver-function that won't.

I will attach my code - most of you would definitely code a calculator much different and especially much shorter than the way I did it but I am proud I got this far, so please don't judge me too harshly! :D

First the declaration of functions which worked perfectly in the test.js. The solver was originally designed to return the previous 4 functions in a nested way but I thought this might be the problem, so I changed it.

```
function adds(num1, num2) {
    return num1+num2;
};

function subs(num1, num2) {
    return num1-num2;
};
function muls(num1, num2) {
    return num1*num2;
};
function divis(num1, num2) {
    return num1/num2;
};

//Creates an array with string elements.
function createArray(string) {
    let array = [];
    for(let element of string) {
        array.push((element));
    }
    return array;
};

//Returns an array where numbers are joint within one element (e.g. '1','2' becomes '12').
function joinNums(array) {
    let numArray = [''];
    let index = 0;

    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(array[i]))) {
            index ++;
            numArray.push(array[i]);
            index++;
            numArray[index]=[''];
            continue;
        }
    numArray[index] =numArray[index] + array[i];
    }
    return numArray;
};

//Returns an array where all elements with numbers in them are changed to proper numbers instead of strings. 
function makeNums(array) {
    let numArray = [''];
    let index = 0;

    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(array[i]))) {
            index ++;
            numArray.push(array[i]);
            index++;
            numArray[index]=[''];
            continue;
        }
    numArray[index] = parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return numArray;
};

//Calculates the array that is provided and returns a single number as solution.
function operate(array) {
    let solution = array[0];
    for(let iOp = 1; array.length >= iOp; iOp=iOp+2) {
        if(array[iOp] === '+') {
            solution = adds(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '-') {
            solution = subs(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '*') {
            solution = muls(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '/') {
            solution = divis(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
    }
    return solution;
};

//Takes a string (meant to be the value of a textfield) and returns the solution by calling all previously declared helper functions.
function solver(string) {
    let cr =  createArray(string);
    let jo =  joinNums(cr);
    let ma =  makeNums(jo);
    let op =  operate(ma);
    return op;
};
```

Now on to the input field and hitting the enter-button:

```
//This is the enter-button
let enter = document.getElementById("enter");
//This is the textfield where calculations are entered. The textfield is then meant to be changed to display the operations result.
let textfield = document.getElementById("resultLn");
//The eventlistener.
enter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textfield.value = solver(textfield.value);
    });
```

Comment: Probably need to see your HTML, form controls behave differently depending on certain factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not use `let` statement at the `for` cycles `i` operand (at function `joinNums`, `makeNums`).
In addition at function `operate`, you can use `switch`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this must have been it! I wonder why it worked in the console though. Thank you, thank you, thank you! :)

Comment: The console let you use variables without initialize, but when run on production, the browser very strict.

Answer (score 0):

***Hi***,

Your calculator code works well, If there was a problem, checkout your html.

I test with some operations and it works well. If there any operation doesn't work, please type this operation to help you

```js
//This is the enter-button
let enter = document.getElementById("enter");
//This is the textfield where calculations are entered. The textfield is then meant to be changed to display the operations result.
let textfield = document.getElementById("resultLn");
//The eventlistener.
enter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    textfield.value = solver(textfield.value);
    });

function adds(num1, num2) {
    return num1+num2;
};

function subs(num1, num2) {
    return num1-num2;
};
function muls(num1, num2) {
    return num1*num2;
};
function divis(num1, num2) {
    return num1/num2;
};

//Creates an array with string elements.
function createArray(string) {
    let array = [];
    for(let element of string) {
        array.push((element));
    }
    return array;
};

//Returns an array where numbers are joint within one element (e.g. '1','2' becomes '12').
function joinNums(array) {
    let numArray = [''];
    let index = 0;

    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(array[i]))) {
            index ++;
            numArray.push(array[i]);
            index++;
            numArray[index]=[''];
            continue;
        }
    numArray[index] =numArray[index] + array[i];
    }
    return numArray;
};

//Returns an array where all elements with numbers in them are changed to proper numbers instead of strings. 
function makeNums(array) {
    let numArray = [''];
    let index = 0;

    for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(parseInt(array[i]))) {
            index ++;
            numArray.push(array[i]);
            index++;
            numArray[index]=[''];
            continue;
        }
    numArray[index] = parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    return numArray;
};

//Calculates the array that is provided and returns a single number as solution.
function operate(array) {
    let solution = array[0];
    for(let iOp = 1; array.length >= iOp; iOp=iOp+2) {
        if(array[iOp] === '+') {
            solution = adds(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '-') {
            solution = subs(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '*') {
            solution = muls(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
        
        if(array[iOp] === '/') {
            solution = divis(solution, array[iOp+1]);
        }
    }
    return solution;
};

//Takes a string (meant to be the value of a textfield) and returns the solution by calling all previously declared helper functions.
function solver(string) {
    let cr =  createArray(string);
    let jo =  joinNums(cr);
    let ma =  makeNums(jo);
    let op =  operate(ma);
    return op;
};
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="resultLn">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The html was alright. One user suggested I did not use let in the for-loop. Even though the code worked in the console without it, this must have been it.